# Cleanest way to check an incremented index in a closure in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, closures

I have the following closure and I am a little unsure about how to check if the index (which is incremented each time the closed-over function is called) should be reset.  It seems like resetting the `index` value, whose previous value was used one line before could cause some problems.

Is this the correct way to access both the current index, and future index, and increment it in Javascript or is their a more praxis-approved solution?

```
var autoChange = (function () {
    var index = 0;
    var imageIds = [
        'one',
        'two',
        'three'
    ];

    return function () {
        var oldImage = document.querySelector('#' + imageIds[index]);
        if (++index === imageIds.length) {
            index = 0;
        }
        var newImage = document.querySelector('#' + imageIds[index]);
    };
})();

setInterval(autoChange, 3000);
}
```

Comment: I don't see any problem with what you're doing - it should work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you have should work fine.

You could however avoid the conditional and make the code even more readable using the modulo operator like this:

```
var oldImage = document.querySelector('#' + imageIds[index]);
index = (index + 1) % imageIds.length;
var newImage = document.querySelector('#' + imageIds[index]);
```

Comment: This is how I usually do it.

Comment: Okay, this gets to the root of my question which was, is resetting the `index` in the middle of a function like this "acceptable" javascript style.

Comment: @Startec yes, of course it is.  The advantage of this code is that avoids you having to reason about whether "pre" or "post" increment is used, and it makes the logic completely obvious.

Comment: @Alnitak i wanted to invoke the function returned by `var autoChange = ` (i.e. what is returned from the IIFE)  (in other words, I wanted to invoke the function that is actually incrementing the index each time. Isn't this the correct way?

Comment: my apologies - I didn't spot that you'd already invoked that function with the IIFE before assigning its result to `autoChange`.